# Texas Hold'Em Shotgun Questions

Tags: discussion, spam, flooding

These questions are individually better than the previous set (which seem to have been deleted), but asking a long series of formulaic questions about particular strategic questions in a single game feels like spamming, or at least flooding (posting rapid-fire content that fills up a discussion board or chat room at the expense of everyone else's content). It's overwhelming the front page, and it's not likely that any of these will get good answers in a timely manner.

What's the appropriate action here? Flag these questions? Vote to close? Just vote them down? Individually, they would probably be OK, but as a group, flooding the front page, they seem quite out of place.

- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/408/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-how-to-play-a-tournament
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/409/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-how-to-play-before-the-flop
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/410/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-how-to-play-after-the-flop
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/411/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-raise-sizes-in-different-blind-levels
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/412/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-bet-sizing-how-much-do-you-bet-and-why
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/413/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-odds-and-outs-how-should-you-play-draws
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/414/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-advanced-strategies-for-postflop-play
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/415/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-four-standard-charts-for-the-push-or-fold-stage
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/417/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-how-do-you-play-speculative-hands
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/418/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-the-perfect-introduction-to-multi-tabling
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/419/poker-texas-holdem-sit-and-go-nl-tournament-your-opponents-hand-ranges

I tried flagging these for moderator attention, and I actually ran out of flagging opportunities; apparently, you can only flag 10 posts in one day.

Comment: I just came here to post the same thing.  The *entire* front page of questions is Texas Hold 'em questions.

Comment: @Brian: To clarify, you are complain about the questions or the flood?

Comment: There is also a bit of a problem in that I imagine this may lower our ratio of answered questions artificially, since the interest among the current user group seems to be somewhat lower (currently, five out of the oldest eight questions tagged "poker" have at least one answer, and the remaining eighteen questions have no answers). However, that should hopefully clear up once the beta goes open.

Comment: My main problem with these posts is that they don't seem genuine.  Looks to me like someone is looking to pad their Rep., not get an actual answer.  The questions are very vague, and if I were a mod, I'd probably throw around a warning or two.
As it is, I'll just be voting to close them (all).

Comment: @bigown The flood. Each question is individually OK (though, perhaps would be better for the proposed poker SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3425/poker, but as this one exists and that doesn't, it's OK here for now).

Comment: Why is it even possible to ask 20 questions in a space of 30 minutes? You'd expect that this problem has come up before on SE and has been fixed.

Comment: @Erik: This is not a big problem. It's clear to me that we go high here.

Comment: @Egg: Close is not the solution to everything. In Beta, specially in private we need help users to improve the experience on site. We can comment, discuss here on meta and even down vote if the OP doesn't wanna edit the question. Close is last resource. Just my opinion.

Comment: @Brian: Agreed.

Comment: I've now run out of close votes, flags, and downvotes for the day on these questions... and he's still asking them. I think I need to escalate to the SE staff.

Comment: Look at his profile -- 37 questions for `card-games` and `poker-texas-holdem`... I'm pretty sure he's spamming for the `Taxonomist` badge.

Comment: @Brian Campell AMEN.  This is ridiculous.  I'm surprised there isn't a limit to how many questions you can ask in a given time period.  Perhaps he hasn't just hit it yet.

Comment: team@stackoverflow.com :-)

Comment: Posted on meta.so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68180/how-to-deal-with-flooding-on-a-beta-se I will wait to see if I get a response here or there before contacting team@stackoverflow.com, since I've already done so much flagging, and I don't want to flood the admins with this problem (since all of the SO/SE employees seem to be admins here, they should see the flagging that I've already done, if I understand correctly how it works).

Comment: ... and suspended.

Comment: RobertCartaino is coming to deal with.

Comment: Looks like everything is better now. There appear to have been some comments on this thread that I see snippets of in my inbox, but don't see here; have a few people deleted comments?

Comment: @Brian: I edited my last comment :-)

Answer (score 8):

They're not real, honest, questions, since it's basically copy-and-paste work, so I'm voting to close them as such.

Answer (score 5):

I personally think this feels like spamming and that they are candidates for being closed.  They're very short and all have the same style of how they address people.  I think my frustration, and most peoples frustration with these, is they were all posted at exactly the same time in a flood.  Without knowing poker, I'm not sure which ones are closely related to which other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to merge them all into an uber-strategy thread?

Comment: An uber-strategy thread doesn't really work well on SE. Each question should be relatively specific, and answerable in a single answer (there are also some question that work OK as a poll, listing various options and voting up the best, but even that isn't very good for a strategy thread). A long, detailed discussion of the strategy of a given game probably isn't appropriate for SE; that's better done on a wiki, or a blog, or a book. SE is for specific questions, which may be too specific to cover in a general strategy article or book, but which can be answered and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the garbage I was afraid of when I posted my [question about whether poker was on-topic or not](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/poker-is-it-on-topic). I really wish this hadn't happened.

Comment: I don't think poker is not on topic, SPAM is not on topic!

Answer (score 0):

It did feel like spam to me when they first appeared and flooded the homepage.

But then, this site is only starting and getting lots of questions in seems like a good idea, even at the price of some occasional "discomfort". Maybe poker players feel that this site is being flooded with Dominion questions. :-)

So I'd vote to keep them... For now! Let the up/down voting on each question do its natural work and we can decide near the end of the beta if this type of rapid-firing will be allowed after the beta.

Comment: Well, this problem has been dealt with now. This is not just a bit of discomfort; this is a crucial point in the development of the community, when we're trying to "prime" it with good content. A flood of copy-paste questions is pretty much guaranteed to wind up with bad content. If the questions are so formulaic, and the answers are simply filling in well-known strategy, than SE is probably not a good forum. And any time one user floods and takes over a community, it's bad for everyone else, beta or not. It stops being a community and just starts being theirs alone.